# Lower Timeframe Volume Bars

Tags: plot, pine-script

On a 5m chart,  I am trying to plot volume bars that are colored partially green and partially red, in accordance with the red/green volume of the five 1m volume bars that comprise the 5m volume bar.

I thought this would be pretty straight forward, but I am running into problems calculating the volume from the preceding five 1m indice via the `security()` function.

The way I see it, the following code should give me the same value for both of the `plotchar()` calls.

However, this is not the case!

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
//@version=4
study("LTF Vol", format=format.volume, overlay=false)

1mVol = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", volume)

5mVol = security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", volume)

sumFive1mVol = 1mVol[0] + 1mVol[1] + 1mVol[2] + 1mVol[3] + 1mVol[4]

plotchar(sumFive1mVol, char="", color=color.red, title="sumFive1mVol")

plotchar(5mVol, char="", color=color.blue, title="5mVol")
```

P.S. I realize that I can eventually use `sum(source, length)` in order to define my `sumFive1mVol`, but I spelled it out here in order to be as explicit as possible -- and in order to help hunt down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `security()` at intrabar resolutions is not supported and will impose important constraints on your script (no realtime data, no alerts, etc.). See [this article](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#is-it-possible-to-use-security-on-lower-intervals-than-the-charts-current-interval) for a discussion of them and example code.

If you nonetheless interested in looking at code doing what you need, see my [Delta Volume Columns Pro](https://www.tradingview.com/script/F2ylEYOO-Delta-Volume-Columns-Pro-LucF/) indicator, which mines intrabar volume to build delta volume information.

*Disclosure: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry. I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.*

Comment: Thanks, LucF.  I will take a look at your Delta Volume script.  However, although I understand that plotting lower timeframe info on a higher timeframe chart can be problematic, shouldn't Pine Script still be able to provide the correct calculations--that is, shouldn't ```1mVol[0] + 1mVol[1] + 1mVol[2] + 1mVol[3] + 1mVol[4]``` that is called on a 5m chart result in the same volume total as a single 5m bar?

Comment: You have 5 "1min" intrabars contained in each chart bar, and there is no Pine syntax to refer to each one individually. Your notation is fetching the last 1min bar of each of the chart's 5min bars. That's why you need a function like I use that runs on each intrabar and detects the first one using the change in time. The FAQ article and my code comments explain what going on.

Comment: Ok thanks — I’ll look at your code to see if I can disentangle that.

Comment: My [Bar Balance](https://www.tradingview.com/script/lcgCwWwI-Bar-Balance-LucF/) thing also uses the same concept, but in a different way, to count the up/down intrabars inside a chart bar. So it's using the same framework, but applying different logic inside the functions called at intrabar resolution. Could also be useful to inspect that code.