# Variable not updated on each tick

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a simple script that would just count ticks and draw a line to follow ticks count on each bar. I'm a developer, familiar with code, so I've tried a lot of different ways to achieve that including using global variables, local variables, arrays, even using `strategy(calc_on_every_tick=true)` instead of `study()` to try to trick the system... nothing worked.

Here's the simplest try that I've made and which the PineScript beginner that I am would expect to work but doesn't :

```
//@version=4

study(
     title="Tick Count",
     overlay=false,
     precision=0)

//
// Global variables
//

var int lastTickTime = na
var int tickCount = 0

//
// Processing
//

if (barstate.isrealtime)
    lastTickTime := timenow
    tickCount := tickCount + 1

//
// Plots
//

plot(tickCount)
plot(lastTickTime)
```

`lastTickTime` is correctly updated in real time, which means the script enters the `if` as expected on each tick. However it doesn't update `tickCount` on each tick too as expected, but only on the first tick of each bar.

Why is PineScript updating one value but not the other? How can I force it, if it's possible, to update and repaint `tickCount` on each tick? If it's not possible, why? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Pine Script behaves differently on realtime bars, than it does on historical bars.
You don't see the tick increments because of the rollback process that occurs on realtime bars.
For each tick change in the realtime bar, the user variables are rolled back to the state they had at the opening of that realtime bar.

That's why you constantly see `tickCount` having value `1`.
It's inital state is `0` and `1` is added to that `0` at every tick.

The reason why you see `lastTickTime` with the correct value, is that although it's being reset to it's inital state of `na` on each tick, it also gets assigned the value `timenow` at every tick, which is always the current time.

See [Execution Model - Calculation based on realtime bars](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html#calculation-based-on-realtime-bars) for an explanation on the rollback process.

Excerpt from that link:

*To summarize the realtime bar process:*

- *A script executes at the open of the realtime bar and then once per
  update.*
- *Variables are rolled back before every realtime update.*
- *Variables are committed once at the closing bar update.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, it makes sense now. Ultimately I'm not interested in the tick count, what I really want is to track intra-bar ups and downs in an array, to then take trading decisions based on these values. That tick count thing was just a test to see what's possible or not in PineScript. Since it's not possible because of the rollback process, is it possible instead to get `close` values for bars in a lower timeframe? For example if timeframe is `15min` and `5min` left then get last 10 `close` values on the `1min` timeframe. I think so, using `security()`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Using `security()` at intrabar resolutions is not supported, but see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351375/lower-timeframe-volume-bars).  You might find some code you can use in the Delta Volume Columns Pro indicator in that answer.

Comment: There might be a solution for your problem. TradingView officialy just released the [`varip`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_varip) keyword that enables variables to retain their values between the updates of a real-time bar.

Comment: Woohoo right at the time I need it! Thanks a lot for letting me know!

Comment: A publication on how `varip` works has just been published. See [Using varip variables](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ppQxBISk-Using-varip-variables-PineCoders/)